# What's the best DRY way to repeat a class based view in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have an app that acts as a booker for the end-user; it's basically a form that calls various apis (BookerApp). It uses two main APIs but in different ways; It calls Google to get geo-location (retrieving lat-long data) to pass through the second api. The issue is I need to use this app in main WebsiteApp and its subsequent templates but with slight modification to the appearance (templates). I know I can repeat the CBV in the website app and modify the leading rendered template file; but was wondering if there was a better DRY method for this? Here is the current structure

```
Project folder >
|___ MainProject
          |__ settings.py
          |__ urls.py
          |__ settings.py

|___ WebsiteApp
          |__ Templates
          |__ views.py <----- repeat the same CBV (found in booker) to here with DRY method
          |__ urls.py
          |__ etc..

|___ BookerApp
          |__ Templates
          |__ views.py <--- CBV held here
          |__ etc..

|___ Static
```

I hope this makes sense; I know my project is all over the place and any recommendations would be welcome.

In essence the app in Booker is basically a complicated form that I want to be able to use in other templates (mostly held in the WebsiteApp folder without having to repeat the CBV in that particular views file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can by using inheritance. Create a custom class

```
class Obect(object):
```

Then override any of the standard methods within the object class that are found in cbv's

What I usually do is the above, then let a template view inherit my custom class and just say pass. I then use this class in my newly created classes for specific urls.

To take this one step further, every cbv has a get context data method. Which then passes to the render to response method. Your get context data could pass different kwargs to render something dynamic in render to response. So to your point, one could pass just the website kwarg which will be captured in render to response and show just website related context

At the end of the day you are just dealing with python classes and understanding the request and response cycle of the methods within cbv. ccbv.co.uk is cool for this.

I'm happy to elaborate on this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I thought inheritance was the solution but didn't really know how Django would use it. I'll check out that site and come back to you if with any questions (specifics) much appreciated :)